# Flutter: Animate a widget's height back to its original content height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, dart-null-safety

I've always wondered about this seeing as `AnimatedContainer` is pretty flexible. What got me confused is if we can animate a `Container` to be smaller than the actual content, how do we tell it to go back to the default content height?  This being the height of the content is dependent on what is inside it.

I have no real use case for this right now but I can see this being used if, for example, the container had a `ListView' inside (hereby not showing the offset error).

I tried using `null` but apparently it can't be nullable.

```dart
double height = 100;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          height = height == 100 ? null : 100;
        });
      },
      child: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          curve: Curves.bounceOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          width: 100,
          height: height,
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          child: Text('This text set to be much larger than 100 aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa.',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          )
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

Error

```dart
Error: A value of type 'double?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'double' because 'double?' is nullable and 'double' isn't.
            height = height == 100 ? null : 100;
```

I'm trying to approach this through implicit animation but I'm guessing the answer would be an explicit one. Hoping to hear what you guys have in mind.

**Edit:**

Not used here but the same problem applies to using `Tween<double>(begin: 100, end: null).animate(_somecontroller);` where `null` is not a valid argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `null` to the `height` variable when you defined it as `non-nullable`, change your variable to this:

```
double? height = 100;
```

but you can't use `bounded` and `unbounded` height for `AnimatedContainer`, this is full example of what you can do:

```
class TestAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestAnimation> createState() => _TestAnimationState();
}

class _TestAnimationState extends State<TestAnimation> {
  double? height;
  GlobalKey textKey = GlobalKey();
  double textHeight = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        final textKeyContext = textKey.currentContext;
        if (textKeyContext != null) {
          final box = textKeyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          textHeight = box.size.height;
          height = textHeight;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          height = height == 100 ? textHeight : 100;
        });
      },
      child: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 1000,
          ),
          curve: Curves.bounceOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          width: 100,
          height: height,
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          child: Text(
            'This text set to be much larger than 100 aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa.',
            key: textKey,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @enchance was it what you want?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was hoping there was another method other than using `addPostFrameCallback()` but it seems it's also the logical solution seeing as the only way to find the height is to build it first.